# Caused by: yii\base\ErrorException mkdir(): Permission denied - YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I am getting this exception. How can I fix it?

```
Exception – yii\base\Exception
Failed to create directory "/var/www/html/sitr/runtime/cache": mkdir(): Permission denied
↵
Caused by: yii\base\ErrorException
mkdir(): Permission denied
in /var/www/html/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php at line 624
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/sitr/runtime
```

runtime folder keeps generating the files, allow it to do that.

Comment: there are 2 folders as I remember in yii2, check the web sever logs and share the error

Comment: I'm using apache. but I can't find the httpd file in /var/logs/

Comment: the logs will tell you the exact error. On app side, you will be getting http 500

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /radar/web/site/login was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

how to fix?

Comment: your project name is sitr and you are calling radar??  and the basic version of yii2 is like web/index.php?r=site/login

Comment: PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats))

Answer (score -2):

`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/sitr/runtime`

Comment: Including `chmod 777` in an answer without explanation and appropriate warnings is setting up another user of Stack Overflow to introduce a security flaw into their environment.